# I Can't install tortoisesvn 64 bit on windows 7

Tags: tortoise-svn

Every time i try to install tortoisesvn x64 on windows seven it says "This intallation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid windoes installer package." i tried installing the 32 bit one but it says to install the 64 bit one. please help

Comment: Is your Windows 7 64-bit? What exactly is the error message when "it says to install the 64 bit one" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Microsoft Fixit install and uninstall troubleshooter.](http://support2.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall)
It can automatically fix many problems with installing and uninstalling software especially with programs that use the Microsoft installer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old subject, but i had the same issue today and I found this post.

For those who have this issue, try to re-download the installer. Check the size of the file you downloaded (at the time I write it's about 17,9 mo)

Worked for me, hope it helps someone!